# Anonymous User access to Amazon opensearch Dashboard

Tags: amazon-opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

I have created a public facing Opensearch domain.
When i created this domain, I was able to access and open the dashboard and also execute commands using the Dev tools. I used the Master user name and password to authenticate.

However now when i try accessing the dashboard URL, I am getting this error

```
{"Message":"User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: es:ESHttpGet because no resource-based policy allows the es:ESHttpGet action"}
```

I don't get the authentication screen any longer asking me to authenticate. [Have tried clearing my cookies, going incognito but to no avail]

Below is my access policy for my domain and I included the sourceIP based on this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/ac.html#ac-types-ip).

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::************:root"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-west-2:********:domain/internetdomain/*",
      "Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": "xx.XX.abc.xyz/32"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

xx.XX.abc.xyz : is my public ip as i get from https://www.whatismyip.com/ip/

I have two questions.
a) How can i get that authentication sceren for the dashboard URL?
b) How do i get rid of this anonymous user not allowed to access request ? Will anonymous users access the dashboard?

Earlier my access policy didn't have the sourceIP condition and yet it worked. After some time, even with or without the SourceIp condition, I get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this issue by going to Amazon OpenSearch Service > Domains and then select you domain in my case it is -> aes-siem and then select security configuration tab click edit and then go to access policy and select json and under this--

```
"Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": [
            "10.0.0.0/8",
            "172.16.0.0/12",
            "192.168.0.0/16",
            "<Your ip>/32"
          ]
        }
      }
```

and then click on save changes